# In Jmeter, JDBC Request is returning only name of column with no values for a Select query

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

My Environment: JMeter v3.2, Oracle 11, java 1.8

I am able to successfully establish JDBC connection to the database using JDBC Connection Configuration. 
However, the JDBC Request in which i am executing a select query.
I am getting only the name of the column in result with empty value.
I've confirmed the SQL is fine by running the SQL in Oracle Developer, data is returned successfully.

My workings:

JDBC Request --> Query Type: Select Statement 
select policy_code from bas_policy where policy_code='KP550     '
When I run the JDBC Request - the report in the View Results Tree Listener shows successful execution.

**Response data in Debug Sampler:**

```
JMeterVariables: 
JMeterThread.last_sample_ok=true
JMeterThread.pack=org.apache.jmeter.threads.SamplePackage@15ec91
Pool1=org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement
$DataSourceComponentImpl@cfef05
START.HMS=164422
START.MS=1496936662485
START.YMD=20170608
TESTSTART.MS=1496939556814
a_#=0
result=[]
```

Where 'a' is defined as the Variable name.

**Response data in Debug Sampler**

POLICY_CODE

Again, as with all my posts, I am grateful for all advice/help etc.

Comment: Half-Solved. It is working for some of the database but not for some other database. Also, for some other database , even the connection is not getting established. puzzled.

Comment: SOLVED. Have to use the VPD id for the child instance in the query. the correct query is                     select POLICYN,STATUS from bas_policy@cloud_dbid_3.world

Comment: if your question is solved, please post an answer and click "accept answer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. Have to use the VPD (virtual private database) id for the child instance in the query. the correct query is select POLICYN,STATUS from bas_policy@cloud_dbid_3.world